# Magento2: Equivalent catalogsearch/layer getFilterableAttributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, catalogsearch, layer

What is the equivalent in magento2 of

```
$query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/layer');

$filterableAttributes = $query->getFilterableAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to achieve it.

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$filterableAttributes = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);
```

**Note:** I will not recommend to use `$objectManager`